# Retrieve annotations from KType

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, jvm, kotlin

I have a simple `TYPE_USE` annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE_USE, ElementType.TYPE_PARAMETER})
public @interface Cool {
}
```

And the following sample Kotlin class:

```
class Item(
        id: Long? = null,
        var names: List<@Cool String> = emptyList())
```

Is there any way to extract the annotation using Java reflection?

`Item.class.getMethod("getName").getAnnotatedReturnType()` loses the annotations, same with getting the field.

Can I even get the annotation from Kotlin?

`Item::class.memberProperties.elementAt(0).returnType` return a `KType` which has the annotation, but I don't see a way to extract it. Nor to obtain an `AnnotatedType` from `KType`, even though I have JDK8 extensions.

All I see is `KType#javaType` but this returns `Type`, not `AnnotatedType`... so it looses the annotations again.

Comment: Not from Java, because the concept of a "property" does not exist in Java and its annotations are instead kept as string metadata or applied to a synthetic method instead.

Comment: @Moira But this annotation exactly _is_ on the `String` type, and not on a property. So there's no reason for it to become unavailable...

Comment: Yes, but this is a type argument of a property (`names`). If you look at the decompiled class you can see that it is not compiled to an annotation.

Comment: @Moira OK, thanks. Is there a way to still recover it, using Kotlin interop utils, just as `JvmClassMappingKt` or similar? Or obtain `AnnotatedType` from Kotlin itself? I can't seem to even get the annotation from Kotlin, as `KType` offers no obvious way.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>**Edit: [this is a bug and has been reported](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-16795)**. There is not yet a target version, but its priority has been set to Major.</strike> This was fixed in Kotlin 1.3.

---

<strike>TL; DR: no...?</strike>

---

The item annotated with `@Cool` is the first type argument, so you need to retrieve it:

```
val type = Item::class.memberProperties.elementAt(0).returnType

val arg = type.arguments[0]
println(arg) // KTypeProjection(variance=INVARIANT, type=@Cool kotlin.String)
```

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a way to retrieve the annotations on a `KType` (as you have mentioned).

Strangely, this is a very internal process. Looking into the source for [`KTypeImpl`](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/core/reflection.jvm/src/kotlin/reflect/jvm/internal/KTypeImpl.kt) shows that `toString` is implemented via `ReflectionObjectRenderer.renderType(type)`, (where type is a `KotlinType`) which is delegated to `DescriptorRenderer.FQ_NAMES_IN_TYPES`, which we can see is [a `DescriptorRenderer` with modifiers `ALL`](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/core/descriptors/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/renderer/DescriptorRenderer.kt#L122).

The renderer checks if the type is a subclass of `kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.annotations.Annotated`, and then accesses its `annotations` property.

I tried this:

```
val retType = Item::class.memberProperties.elementAt(0).returnType

val arg = retType.arguments[0]
println(arg) // KTypeProjection(variance=INVARIANT, type=@Cool kotlin.String)

val type = arg.type!!
println(type)

val field = type::class.memberProperties.first { it.name == "type" }
val kotlinType = field.call(type) as Annotated
println(kotlinType)

println(kotlinType.annotations)
```

Unfortunately, I get a `ClassNotFoundException` for `org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.KotlinType`, so *that* option is gone.

Equally strangely, `KType` is not a subtype of `KAnnotatedElement` (which is why it has no `annotations` property).

I suppose this may have been an oversight, since `KTypeImpl` wraps a `KotlinType`, which *does* contain annotations.

Comment: Wow. Did **not** see this coming. Thanks for the detailed analysis!

Comment: This is irritating - I just ran into a case where I myself need this :/ hope it gets fixed someday, since it's been an issue for a few years...

Comment: Apparently, according to the issue tracker, this was finally fixed in Kotlin 1.3.