# Kotlin: `tailrec` on Instance method vs Extension function

Tags: kotlin, tail-recursion

In the below code, I see a warning `no tail calls found`, but the same function, when written as extension function, doesn't have that warning. Now I am confused whether my IDE is wrong, or my Extension method is not actually tail-recursive or is there a difference between how compiler deals with Instance methods vs Extension functions.
[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60202108/why-it-is-not-a-tail-recursion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the second warning

> Recursive call is not a tail call​

indicates, this call is recursive, but is not a tail call.

This is because the function is being invoked with a different instance as its target (`next` and not `this`), so `tailrec` doesn't really have an effect in this case. If you replace the target with `this`, the compiler stops issuing any warnings.

I assume the extension function compiles without any warnings because they are compiled as static (i.e. non-instance) functions, where the target is simply another parameter, meaning that the transformed code looks (roughly) like

```
@Nullable
public static final SLLNode2 getNodeForValue2(@NotNull SLLNode2 $this$getNodeForValue2, int valToFind) {
    Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull($this$getNodeForValue2, "$this$getNodeForValue2");
    if ($this$getNodeForValue2.getValue() == valToFind) {
        return $this$getNodeForValue2;
    } else {
        SLLNode2 var10000 = $this$getNodeForValue2.getNext();
        return var10000 != null ? getNodeForValue2(var10000, valToFind) : null;
    }
}
```

which quite clearly contains a recursive tail call.

---

However, I'm not sure this distinction is intentional, since the way extension functions are compiled should be an implementation detail, and the instance function example *should*(?) be equivalently optimizable.

---

Edit: it seems this is in fact a [bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-26038).

Comment: There is a bug to make this work on the Kotlin bug tracker, but not actively worked on :( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60202108/why-it-is-not-a-tail-recursion

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov thanks! I figured this might be the case. Unfortunately, these small Kotlin bugs seem to [pop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47737623/throws-has-no-effect-when-the-target-is-a-property) [up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47717542/kotlin-illegalaccesserror-with-and-for-delegated-interface/47719143#47719143) a [lot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48948311/retrieve-annotations-from-ktype/48948854#48948854) and tend to take a while to fix :/